# How i can show message between variables?

Tags: php, variables

I have variables such as :

```
$type1=10;
$type2=40;
$type3=70;
   .
   .
   .
 and more
```

but this variables not stable because i get them from forms.

And also I have one variable :

```
$total=30;
```

I want to

```
 if `$total` less than `$type1` =>show special message.
 if `$total` between `$type1` & `$type2` =>show special message2.
 if `$total` between `$type2` & `$type3` =>show special message3.
          and more...
```

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: your question is a hint to the code you need. Look out for the `if`s

Comment: use for loop and if inside forloop

Comment: My problem that is my vars not stable.and I get it's from forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$type1=10;
$type2=40;
$type3=70;

$total=30;

$n=10;//count of variables you have
for ($i=0; $i <= $n; $i++) { 
    $v = $GLOBALS['type'.$i];
    $nv = (isset($GLOBALS['type'.$i+1])?isset($GLOBALS['type'.$i+1]):false);
    if($total < $v){
        echo '$total is lesser than $type'.$i;
    }elseif(isset($nv) && $v < $total && $total < $nv){
        echo '$total is between $type'.$i.'and $type'.$i+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh... globals. What if you're using classes, namespaces, functions?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the usual if-statements? If you're getting the values from a form, you can simply assign those values to different variables and use that in your `if` statements to make comparisons.

```
$type1= $_POST['type3'];
$type2= $_POST['type3'];
$type3= $_POST['type3'];

if($total < $type1) {
    //show special message
}
if($total < $type2 && $total1 > $type1) {
    //show special message 2
}
if($total < $type3 && $total > $type2) {
    //show special message 3
}
if(...) {
...
}
```

Comment: My problem that is my vars not stable.and I get it's from forms

Comment: @user2695921: see the second sentence in my answer.

Comment: And my second problem that's var's count is not stable,and var counts is variable.